# Large LLMs for understanding chemical compounds/ toxic substances

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model

I am new to AI and spent the past week gaining as much insight as possible on the topic of generative AI. Please bear with me, if part of my question might still be very basic.

The **scope** of my project is to use a Large Language Model to retrieve data from a couple of thousand reports on contamination (already stored in a pandas dataframe). The information I want to retrieve are i) toxic substances, chemical compounds, etc. and ii) the affected medium (groundwater, etc.). This will be - at one point - extended.

To give you an **example**:

*Report*:  "On March 23rd, a rupture in a 30-inch diameter underground pipeline released approximately 50,000 gallons of crude oil onto the surrounding soil and rock formations. The spill posed a significant threat to both human health and the environment. Lab tests revealed elevated levels of toxic chemicals in the soil and groundwater, including: Benzene: 12 parts per billion (ppb)(Maximum Contaminant Level (MCL): 5 ppb) Toluene: 47 ppb (MCL: 100 ppb) Ethylbenzene: 68 ppb (MCL: 700 ppb) Xylenes: 95 ppb (MCL: 100 ppb) Total PAHs: 250 nanograms per liter (ng/L) (MCL: 10 ng/L) To mitigate the effects of the spill, we immediately deployed a team to contain the damage and clean up the area. We excavated contaminated soil, installed a soil vapor extraction system, and implemented a groundwater treatment system.  Regular monitoring and testing will ensure the effectiveness of our cleanup efforts and track the dissipation of contaminants over time. We are also investigating the root cause of the pipeline failure to prevent similar incidents in the future."

The **answers** would be i) Benzene, Toluene, Ethylbenzene, Xylenes, and Polycyclic Aromatic Hydrocarbons and ii) groundwater and soil.

As I have been browsing models and datasets on HuggingFace, I realized I will probably have to fine-tune an existing model with a training dataset. However, I would like to try both options i) prompt engineering AND ii) fine-tuning.

Going further at this point, I have three questions:

1. I identified NLP models for **"Questions Answering"** as the most suitable for my scenario, would you agree?
2. (setting up my training dataset for **fine-tuning** in HuggingFace right now:) What does the key **"answer_start"** in the column "answer" usually stand for (e.g. of the [squad dataset](https://huggingface.co/datasets/squad_v2?row=0))? Does this have something to do with tokens? And if so, how can I reproduce/ declare this in my dataset?
3. I am aware it might be a long stretch to try using an off-the-shelf model with such a domain-specific task, but could you anyways recommend me a model to at least try **prompt engineering** on my data? I was thinking about the **FLAN-T5** or **BART** base model as I will need the encoder-decoder architecture.

Thank you!

Comment: A problem I could imagine is defining which substances are toxic. It is not an easy question and I would not leave it to an LLM that is mostly trained on the public internet and all its ads/prejudice. If you have some kind of list of toxic substances, expand that to include alternative and colloquial names, and scan the texts for those, I would integrate that into the solution. Don't know if feasible.

Comment: Yes, I understand. In a very early version of this retrieval (Regex based text mining) I created a dataframe containing most common toxins and their abbreviations/ acronyms. Good advice to also include the colloquial name. Thanks! 
If I understand you correctly you would advice against prompt engineering?

Comment: I do think prompt engineering would help. Let's say your regex-mining reveals 'Uranium' in the report, but the text says "no traces of Uranium could be found".

Comment: Exactly, regex naturally not being able to distinguish between absence or presence of substances was the major reason I now want to apply LLMs.